# |$q^2$-$p*r$|=prime(n)#

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, primorial

With three consecutive primes p,q,r |$q^2$-$p*r$|=prime(n)#.  There are two solutions of 7,11,13 and 17,19,23 for 3#=30 and two solutions of 97,101,103 and 107,109,113 for 4#=210.  Do you think there are any other solutions for higher primorials?  At least one or perhaps two?

Comment: To me 5#=2*3*5 and 7#=2*3*5*7=210.  I didn't know that OEIS is using the index and not the prime itself.  This means I am asking to find the next primorial 2*3*5*7*11=2310 or 30030 or greater.

Comment: I agree, but I am a classicist who uses retro math symbols and does not even own a television.  I, like other oldsters, still keeps thinking of skip to the next line by pulling the arm on a manual typewriter for carriage return.

Comment: http://primes.utm.edu/glossary/xpage/Primorial.html for a second and more reasonable definition of primorial because it parallels factorials.

Comment: $1699^2-1667\cdot 1733=2310=p_5\#$ but those three primes are not consecutive.